# Does assigning same value to datatype decrease efficiency?

Tags: java, performance, memory-efficient, space-efficiency

For example, I have an infinite while loop which keeps assigning true to our testBool:

```
boolean testBool;

while(true) {

    testBool = true;

    ...more logic...
}
```

Are we wasting computation on reassigning the same value to our datatype, or are languages smart enough to recognize this inefficiency?

Comment: Does it matter? If more logic is very expensive, it doesn't matter. And a smart compiler would move testBool in a register or even hoist it out of the loop if it sees it is a constant.

Comment: I would say depends on the use. In a case of `if(condition){bool=false;}else{bool=true}`, I would do it as `bool=true; if(condition){bool=false}`. Both might be same, but I find it good.

Comment: always strive to make your endless loops as efficient as possible ;-)

Comment: @pveentjer, the question is aimed for theory. I'm simply trying to understand what would happen here behind the curtains. Eventually I would like to ask the same question for a situation with thousands of datatypes that are constantly assigned the same value, to understand the impact of re-assigning the same value repeatedly.

Comment: @Henry, I understand. I'm not adapting this to anything I have, it's just a random thought I had, and I wanted to understand the affect of this situation.

Comment: @Mritunjay Well, I would do `bool = !(condition);` in this case.

Comment: @Henry, I wanted to put an example, there might be some code before `bool=false`. Anyways, let's not deviate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smart compiler would pull it out of the loop.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion

Comment: Thank you for finding the term, this is exactly what I was looking for.